# POST with JSON in format DateTime

Tags: objective-c, json, datetime, rest, nsdate

Im struggling a lot with how I can format a NSDate to POST it as JSON to REST service .net. The accepted format is:

```
"Date":"\/Date(459842400000+0200)\/"
```

I have no problem with the response and to parse it to NSDate. I use JSONFramework for parsing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes.

From your example it looks like you want to build a string with `Date(Timestamp + TimeZone)`. There are two methods that do that, `timeIntervalSince1970` (`NSDate`) and `timeZone` (NSDateFormatter).

Comment: Yes I looked at both of them, but the thing is when I try to pass the above in the HTTPbody i get a warning about unknown escape sequence "\/". But when doing the same with wizTool restClient its accepted.

Comment: Im not sure but could there be any conflict when creating the jsonRepresentation? What I can se the jsonRepresentation removes the first \ from start and end of "Date":"\/Date(459842400000+0200)\/"